# How to change balloonText in amchart

Tags: javascript, web, amcharts

I'm using real time amchart and I want to add date to the balloonText, this is the code:

```
 "balloonText": "<img src='javascripts/images/info.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 5px; width:28px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>[[value]]</b></span><img src='javascripts/images/time.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 5px; width:28px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>[[category]]</b></span>",
```

I want to add today's date next to [[category]], how?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Show us your code and we'll give you some advice in order to improve that. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b>[[category]]"+ new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/') +"</b>
```

Comment: @GhaidaM I would appreciate it a lot if you can pick it as an answer:)